# Load large number of images from URL

Tags: c#, image, listbox, windows-phone

I am actually an Android developer, I faced the problem of memory exception when I am loading large number of images into a `ListBox`.

I have no idea about Windows Phone application development so kindly suggest a better solution to load large number of images into `ListBox` from URL in Windows Phone.

Code is below:

```
 public class listboxrows
    {
        public string text1 { get; set; }
        public string imageUri { get; set; }
        public string text2 { get; set; }
        public string instID { get; set; }
    }

      <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="90" Height="90" Source="{Binding imageUri}" ></Image>
```

I want to know if this is a efficient way to load images from url.

If I have huge number of images it will show an memory exception.

Suggest me a better option where I can load any number of images efficiently without any memory exceptions.

Are there any external projects to achieve my goal?

Comment: the person who down voted at least answer the question

Comment: `ListView` or `ListBox`?

Comment: ListBox control in windows phone

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816569/windows-phone-listbox-with-images-out-of-memory

Comment: they are using bitmap(local image folder). but i am directly binding imageurl to image source.

Comment: Which version of Windows Phone are you targeting?

Comment: Hi madan, have you got the solution for this, I am also facing the same problem, I am loading image from url.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't written actual code to test this, I think the right approach here is to make sure you use data virtualization. [This article](http://shawnoster.com/2010/08/improving-listbox-performance-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-data-virtualization/) provides a good example (even though it's discusses Windows Phone 7 development, it's still applicable).

If there truly is a huge amount of data to display you may want to go further and look at the approach in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx) that further optimizes the work to display items in a `ListBox`.

Of course the standard disclaimer is that a UI where the user has to scroll through a very large number of items isn't necessarily always the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2011/05/wp7dev-tip-2-few-things-to-remember-on.html) will help.

> - **Never bind server-hosted images directly to the  control**, because Silverlight runtime will use the UI thread (using WebClient) to fetch that image from the server, that can make the UI unresponsive for some time.
> - Use a background thread and HttpWebRequest class based implementation to download the image data in an efficient way which finally creates BitmapImage and sets that as the source. A clean MVVM wrapper around this would make your entire Image management pretty easy.