# OutOfMemory Exception in <BitmapImage>.SetSource()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created a pivot that dynamically download and hold several large images.
I first download the image using webclient and write it into disk.
than create an array of image list that holds all the images.
The basic idea is that I only load images when it is needed.
Say there is 12 images in my list. Pivot is showing only 1 image per slide. Assume we are viewing image 7. I proceed to preload image 6 & 8 for next slides.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, {7}, 8], 9, 10, 11, 12
```

When user navigate through slides, I keep the image preloaded between and unload outside "[ ]".

The code I used to preload image:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SetSource(GetStream(fileName);
IMGSource = bi; // IMGSource<ImageSource> referenced by the xaml in Image Binding IMGSource.
```

The code I used to unload images:

```
IMGSource = null;
GC.Collect(); // I force the program to Garbage collect since the image is really large.
```

The problem is, after several image is viewed(about 9 image). It throws an OutOfMemory exception in the line: `bi.SetSource`.

I checked that the unload function had worked properly( it does released the memory after calling Collect, and memory kept at a steady point)

But it still throws an `OutOfMemory` exception.
What should I do?

Edit:
I just discovered that the memory in fact keeps going up
when navigating through slides. By calling:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage;
```

It gives the memories like:

```
54.7 MB, 76.91 MB, 111.94 MB, 105 MB, 112.71 MB, 141.93 MB, 148.42 MB, Exception thrown
```

But by calling:

```
GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
```

It is showing around `1.2~1.3 MB` only.
What happened? Shouldn't the memory being released?

Comment: Please be more sensitive about [formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Sorry I am using my phone to post. It doesn't have a preview for me and I did typed four spaces for codes. But it turns out it didn't worked:\

Comment: That may not be the source of the leak, but you should make sure that you close the stream after loading the picture: `using (var stream = GetStream(fileName)) { bi.SetSource(stream); }`

Comment: Just tested, closing the stream doesn't work. It still throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with setting an Empty 1x1 transparent GIF to the image source the release the memory.

```
public static byte[] EMPTY_IMAGE = new byte[]{
    71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 1, 0, 1
    , 0, 128, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255
    , 0, 0, 0, 33, 249, 4, 1, 0, 0
    , 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
    , 0, 0, 2, 2, 68, 1, 0, 59
};
```

And then just use:

```
bi.SetSource(new System.IO.MemoryStream(MYCLASS.EMPTY_IMAGE));
```

And the memory seems released properly.

Comment: Rather than a 1x1 GIF, you can use a fake picture and catch the exception: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482619/869621

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, could you try setting UriSource to null as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13963747/869621 and see if it works?

Comment: I tried to use new byte[]{0x0} but it thrown me an execption. So that's why I use 1x1 GIF.

Comment: I think UriSource is only available when the source is URI. In my case, the source is a stream from isolated storage. Thus setting the UriSource may not work since the source is a direct stream.