# Memory Leak In WP8 pages

Tags: c#, xaml, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8, garbage-collection

[image: memory graph]

I have created a sample app in which there are two pages.
1st page contains button, on tapping it takes to second page. In second page there is a list of 100 elements.
In this sample I have navigated to and fro from this second page.

So why is this **memory increasing** and why is not going down completely on going back to first page and why **page destructor never gets called**?

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Net;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Windows.Controls;
        using System.Windows.Navigation;
        using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
        using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
        using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Diagnostics;

        namespace PhoneApp1
        {
            public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
            {
                public Page1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        listBitmapImage.Add(new Test(i));
                    }
                }

                List<Test> listBitmapImage = new List<Test>();
                protected override void OnRemovedFromJournal(JournalEntryRemovedEventArgs e)
                {
                    base.OnRemovedFromJournal(e);
                }

                ~Page1()
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("IN DESTRUCTOR");
                }
            }

            public class Test
            {
                int _a;
                string img = "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";
                string img_1, img_2, img3, img4;

                public Test(int a)
                {
                    _a = a;
                    img = a + img;
                    img_1 = a + "1" + img;
                    img_2 = a + "2" + img;
                    img3 = a + "3" + img;
                    img4 = a + "4" + img;
                    Debug.WriteLine("CONSTRUCTOR:{0}", _a);
                }

                ~Test()
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("DESTRUCTOR:{0}", _a);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's [a link  to download sample project.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xk6jlvqw7dz4h7j/mLpuUZD1qS)

Comment: Is `Page1` class your first or second page?

Comment: second page.you can download whole project if u want to see

Comment: Can you try adding a call to `GC.Collect()` in the `OnNavigatedTo` event of Page1, then going to page 2 and back to page 1 three times? If that's the issue I'm thinking about, the first instance of the page should be disposed when you do that for the fourth time.

Comment: I have a similar situation where the page is only garbage collected after the 3rd or 4th time loading it.  What is this issue?

Comment: I have same issue, anybody found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If yo are using BitmapImage, It had memory issue in windows phone 8 already. That may be the reason you are getting memory issue. Please find a [similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355496/cannot-find-the-memory-leak)

[Also this link give you more idea about the issue](http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2013/02/17/wpdev-memory-leak-with-bitmapimage.aspx)

Comment: but i am not using bitmapimage its just the name of list